# Collapsing Toolbar Layout with Custom Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've been experimenting with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in Android. I am trying to change the shape of the `Toolbar` when it's collapsed. [And like this when collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyjXi.jpg).

I want the Toolbar to look [something like this when collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VjCb.jpg). I can do it to a normal `Toolbar` when it's not in a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` by creating a custom background for it as shown above. But I'm not able to set it to the toolbar in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` as setting a background simply leads it to showing up in the expanded view and then shifting upwards when in collapsed form.

Any idea how this can be implemented?

XML Code for the `CollapsingToolbar`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:titleEnabled="true"
            app:title="LOL1"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@color/colorAccent"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:src="@drawable/head"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image: Currently it looks like this when expanded]
[![see image][3]][3]

[3]:

Comment: Ca you put your code here?

Comment: I've added the XML Code.